# How to disable a styled.button in React styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have created the following very basic styled-components styled button:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button``;

export const Button = () => {
    return <StyledButton>Default label</StyledButton>;
};
```

Then when creating an instance of one I am trying to disable it:

```
<Button disabled />
```

VSCode/React is not allowing this, throwing the following error:

```
Type '{ disabled: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
    Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

HTML buttons [have a disabled attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) and the [styled-component docs state](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#primary):

```
StyledComponent
...
This component can take any prop. It passes it on to the HTML node if it's a
valid attribute, otherwise it only passes it into interpolated functions. 
(see Tagged Template Literal)
```

Resulting in me being a bit stumped. Does anyone know why this might be, please?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: you haven't declared any proips to your button

Comment: Spread all props onto the button component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass the prop to the Component and, as you are using strict react, you have to declare type of props:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button``;

export const Button = ({disabled=false}: {disabled: boolean}) => {
    return <StyledButton disabled={disabled}>Default label</StyledButton>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of handling it. Using your example.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
pointer-events:${(props)=>props.disabled?'none':null};
`;

export const Button = () => {
    return <StyledButton disabled={true}>Default label</StyledButton>;
};
```

This makes sure that the button cannot be interacted with using a mouse. But this still allows the button to be clicked via keyboard e.g using 'Enter' key.

Going further, if you are using react. You can implement the below solution.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
    pointer-events:${(props)=>props.disabled?'none':null};
`;

export const Button = () => {
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);

const handleClick = (isDisabled) => {
if(!isDisabled){
//handleOperation
}
}
        
    
return <StyledButton 
        disabled={isDisabled}
        onClick={()=>handleClick(isDisabled)}
        >
        Default label
        </StyledButton>;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to allow props to be examined in the styled component. Like so

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const buttonStyles = css`
  display: true
`;

const invertedButtonStyles = css`
  display: true
`;

const getButtonStyles = (props) => {
   
    return props.inverted ? buttonStyles : invertedButtonStyles;
  };


export const CustomButtonContainer = styled.button`
  ${getButtonStyles}
`;
```